# Sql error number: 512. Error Message: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to run this query in SSMS and I'm getting an error:

> Sql error number: 512. Error Message: Subquery returned more than 1 value

```
MERGE datawarehouse.product t
        USING
        (
            SELECT
            (StyleCode + ColorwaySAPID) as OptionID,
            ColorwayName,
            StyleCode, 
            [Description],
            Division,
            lclChannel,
        
            (select [label] FROM import.enumneckline e 
            inner join import.Product p 
                ON e.Enumeration_Value = p.lclNeckLine2

                ) as NeckLine,

                ValidationFlag,
                ValidationMessage,
                [Timestamp],
                [Customer_Timestamp]

                FROM import.product 

            )   s
         
    ON t.OptionID = s.OptionID

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
            SET
                
t.OptionIDName = s.ColorwayName,
t.StyleID = s.StyleCode,
t.StyleName = s.[Description],
t.DepartmentID = s.Division,
t.RegionChannelName  = s.lclChannel,
t.lclNeckline2 = s.[Neckline],
t.ValidationFlag = 'OK',
T.ValidationMessage = NULL,
T.[Timestamp] = S.[Timestamp],
T.[Customer_Timestamp] = S.[Customer_Timestamp]
    
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
            (
                OptionId,
OptionIDName,
StyleID ,
StyleName,
DepartmentID,
RegionChannelName,
lclNeckline2,
ValidationFlag,
ValidationMessage,
[TimeStamp],
Customer_Timestamp
            )
        VALUES
            (
                s.OptionID,
s.ColorwayName,
s.StyleCode,
s.[Description],
s.Division,
s.lclChannel,
s.[Neckline],
'Ok',
s.ValidationMessage,
s.[TimeStamp],
s.Customer_Timestamp

            );
```

The join is returning only 1 value = 'label' and I am not using the table object for pulling any other data.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

I'm expecting the DWH table to be loaded with the select values.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you change the neckline join in your select statement to be a proper join after the FROM Products statement? Without knowing your data, it's hard to tell what might be causing this

Comment: [help/behavior] [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the problem is with the subquery that returns `NeckLine`:

```
SELECT (StyleCode + ColorwaySAPID) as OptionID,
    ...,
    (
        SELECT [label] 
        FROM import.enumneckline e 
        INNER JOIN import.Product p 
            ON e.Enumeration_Value = p.lclNeckLine2
    ) as NeckLine,
    ...
FROM import.product
```

There is no `WHERE` clause in the subquery that limits which rows are returned, so this brings all rows that match between the two tables.

You are already selecting from `product` in the outer query, so I really suspect that you meant a *correlated* subquery instead:

```
SELECT (StyleCode + ColorwaySAPID) as OptionID,
    ...,
    (
        SELECT [label] 
        FROM import.enumneckline e 
        WHERE e.Enumeration_Value = p.lclNeckLine2  -- correlation here
    ) as NeckLine,
    ...
FROM import.product p                               -- alias for the outer table
```